# Adding chapter numbers to equation numbers in r markdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I want to number equations in a document created using r markdown, output to pdf but I want to include the chapter number in the equation numbering.

I have followed the instructions as shown in https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#equations

The labels in the link include the chapter number but mine don't.

```
---
number_sections: true
fig_caption: yes
title: "Test equation nos"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

# Chapter 1

I would like this equation to be numbered (1.1) but it is just labelled (1)

\begin{equation}
  e = mc^2
  (\#eq:emc)
\end{equation}

# Chapter 2

I would like this equation to be numbered (2.1) but it is labelled (2)

\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi}+1 = 0
  (\#eq:euler)
\end{equation}
```

I would like the equations to be numbered (1.1) and (2.1) they are actually labelled (1) (2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `bookdown::pdf_docuemnt2` uses the LaTeX `article` class, which does not have any chapters. If you explicitly change this to use `book` or `report` class, the equations will be appropriately numbered:

```
---
number_sections: true
fig_caption: yes
title: "Test equation nos"
documentclass: book
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
---

# Chapter 1

I would like this equation to be numbered (1.1) but it is just labelled (1)

\begin{equation}
  e = mc^2
  (\#eq:emc)
\end{equation}

# Chapter 2

I would like this equation to be numbered (2.1) but it is labelled (2)

\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi}+1 = 0
  (\#eq:euler)
\end{equation}
```

However, this will result in a much longer document, since chapters start on a new page etc. If you are interested in a `article` like document with equations numbered per section, you can adept [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106935/how-to-include-chapter-number-in-equation-numbers):

```
---
number_sections: true
fig_caption: yes
title: "Test equation nos"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{amsmath}
    - \numberwithin{equation}{section}
---

# Chapter 1

I would like this equation to be numbered (1.1) but it is just labelled (1)

\begin{equation}
  e = mc^2
  (\#eq:emc)
\end{equation}

# Chapter 2

I would like this equation to be numbered (2.1) but it is labelled (2)

\begin{equation}
  e^{i\pi}+1 = 0
  (\#eq:euler)
\end{equation}
```

You can put these commands also in a  preamble `.tex` file if you are using one.

Comment: Thank you I knew I had to be missing something simple, the report class works well for my application.